# Developing proof writing and logical skills

Tags: proof-writing

What resources can a person turn to in order to develop their proof writing and logical skills? The advanced calculus course I'm taking has made me realize how weak my logic and proof writing skills are, I'm struggling to write even basic set builder proofs.

My goal really is to write elegant and straightforward proofs, avoiding the use of any non-mathematical symbols.

Comment: Rules of Logic will provide you help. Have you consulted to any Logic book or not?

Comment: I think that reading mathematical text books really helps. You not only learn what theorems proove, but you also learn from observing how the proof is written.

Comment: Try the Logic Book by Bergman,Moor and Nelson. It comes with CD if you buy new .lt is about sentential and predicate logic (i.e symbolic logic) It is an excellent text.